# How find out subnet having an IP in Excel vlookup?

Tags: regex, excel, vlookup

What I need to do is to find out the name of the subnet having the following columns:

```
ColumnA          ColumnB     ColumnC             ColumnD
15.100.34.156                10.45.80.0/24       Pre-pro
15.100.34.45                 235.76.89.0/24      Dev-pro
10.45.80.111                 15.100.34.0/24      Int-Cli
```

What I wanted to do is to get the name of subnet from columnD in ColumnB base on IP ColumnA.

=vlokkup(A1;C1:D3,2,true)

I'm trying with the above example but it doesnt work.

Is there any option to use this way with regex?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Excel does not support regex.  Additionally, your task is incompletely specified.  I guess you are content with /24 network lookups but this is not clear from your question.  Traditionally, 10.0.0.0/8 is a single netblock of "class A" but with [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), you can refer to an arbitrary netblock of any size.

Comment: You are right, I've already modified it.

Answer (score 2):

What I finally did, and having in consideration that all my subnets are Clase "C" /24, is:

1. Convert three first block to binary
2. vlookup for Binary column

Them got the result.

```
ColumnA          BinaryA     ColumnC         BinaryC       ColumnE
15.100.34.156    00001111... 10.45.80.0/24   00001010...   Pre-pro
15.100.34.45     00001111... 235.76.89.0/24  11101011...   Dev-pro
10.45.80.111     00001010... 15.100.34.0/24  00001111...   Int-Cli
```

Them:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1;C:E;3;FALSE) //Get column D where B1 match in C:E
```

To get binary address:

```
=CONCATENATE(DEC2BIN(MID(B58;1;FIND(".";B58;1)-1);8);DEC2BIN(MID(B58;FIND(".";B58)+1;FIND(".";B58;(FIND(".";B58)+1)-FIND(".";B58))-1);8);DEC2BIN(MID(B58;FIND(".";B58;FIND(".";B58)+1)+1;FIND(".";B58;FIND(".";B58;FIND(".";B58)+1)+1)-FIND(".";B58;FIND(".";B58)+1)-1);8))
```

Ref:https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/geeky-excel-formulas-subnet-math-group-by-subnet-using-built-in-excel-2010-formulas/